# Angular - Use $sanitize on every input

Tags: angularjs

On my server side I sanitise everything coming in.

On my Angular app client side I've done the same in some instances e.g. contact forms however am now thinking shouldn't I just apply it to every input field?

So I've seen `$sanitize('some string')` however is there a way to just apply it at some top app level rather than having to enter that for every instance input fields is?

(Assuming this is a wise thing to do - if not keen to hear suggestions).

Thanks.

Comment: What would the point be of applying to every input? You can't trust anything from client no matter what you sanitize client side anyway

Comment: What is the point of sanitizing on the client side if things are being re-santized on the server? There are a couple of reasons why you may want to sanitize on the client: faster feedback for the client, or the client is doing something with the data so it needs sanitization locally.  If neither of those hold true, you may as well only sanitize server side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a directive that you will call "input", then it will apply to all inputs of your app.

Inside the directive you can add a parser to $ngModel to apply automatically $sanitize when value changes.

It will looks like this:

```
myApp.directive('input', function($sanitize) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      if(ngModel !== undefined){
        ngModel.$parsers.push(function(value){
          return $sanitize(value);
        });
      }
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Can you please explain it a bit more? Thanks !

Comment: This worked for me very nicely but sadly it messed utf-8 characters like ö ç ş ğ İ ı ü in inputs.