# Angular - How to move custom directive into a separate file

Tags: angularjs

I'm looking at this code:

```
app.directive('resizer', ['$window', function ($window) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {            
            angular.element($window).on('resize', function () {
                $window.innerWidth > 500 ? 
                    elem.addClass('large') : elem.removeClass('large')
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Source: [SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37500306/angular-use-sanitize-on-every-input/37501092#37501092)

I want to place this into a separate file, so in my app dependencies I've done:

`var app = angular.module('app', [.....])
.directive("resizer", resizer)`

and then in that new file I've written:

```
var resizer = function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, elem, attires, $window) {
          angular.element($window).on('resize', function () {
              $window.innerWidth > 500 ?
                  elem.addClass('large') : elem.removeClass('large')
          });
      }
  }
}
```

However its not working - could someone help me understand whats wrong here please.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with the following:

```
angular.module('app').directive('resizer', ['$window', function ($window) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {            
            angular.element($window).on('resize', function () {
                $window.innerWidth > 500 ? 
                    elem.addClass('large') : elem.removeClass('large')
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

you just have to initialize your module before somewhere with its dependencies:

```
angular.module('app', [.....]);
```

---

a reason why your code is not working, might be you named the directive wrong. in the first example you wrote `resizer`, in the 2nd one you named it `resize`.

Comment: Hi - that was a typo I fixed.

Comment: @userMod2: was it the one i wrote about?

Comment: Yep - so its called `resizer`. So with your method I just inject `resizer`